# Add to all elements from an attributes something

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a collection which contains insides these attributes: 
_id, title, year, country. By the way the collection name is movies and it's a Json.

I would like to add before all titles of the document that:

"The title is: ***NameOfTheTitleHere*** "

For example I have that: 
`{"_id": 1,"title": "Gozilla", "year":1998, "country": "USA"}`.

And I want that: `{"_id": 1,"title": "The title is: Gozilla", "year":1998, "country": "USA"}`.

I searched on the doc and the net but I can't find anything. Could someone help me please.

Thanks in avance for anybody who would take the time to help me.

Comment: Could you provide an example and the desired output?

Comment: For example I have that: {"_id": 1,"title": "Gozilla", "year":1998, "country": "USA".And I want "_id": 1,"title": "The title is: Gozilla", "year":1998, "country": "USA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MongoDB v4.2, [db.collection.update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline) allows conditional updates based on current field values or updating one field using the value of another field(s).

```
db.movies.update({},
  [
    {$set:{title:{$concat:["The title is:", " ", "$title"]}}}
  ],
{multi:true})
```

Before v4.2, we need to perform MongoDB aggregation and override collection with `$out` operator:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "title" : { $concat: ["The title is:", " ", "$title"] }
    }
  },
  { $out: "movies" }
])
```